# Unexpected behaviour with flex attributes on child items in Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I am using angular material and their flex attributes on child items in layout containers.

In particular I have row layouts where I want the child items to take up equal space, so I have:

```
<div layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row">
    <md-input-container flex>
        <label>Input</label>
        <input >
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container flex>
        <label translate>Select</label>
        <md-select ng-model="">
            <md-option>
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

But I am finding the first child is wider that the second child.

If however I apply `flex="50"` to the child items, they take up equal space, see Codepen demo - http://codepen.io/parky128/pen/LRPAKZ

This is using the latest release of Angular Material also - 1.1.0

Does this mean I will have to explicitly set the flex percentages where needed? I would have thought in the first example as per my codepen, the two child items would take up equal widths.

**UPDATE**

I have found out I only get this behaviour where I have a row layout containing an input and md-select (both inside md-input-containers).

See - http://codepen.io/parky128/pen/amojra

You can see the first card shows the issue. If you set the flex to flex="50" on these input containers they size nicely.

**UPDATE 2**

Ok so I posted an issue on the AM repo and their response was to stick with using flex=50, otherwise you cannot guarantee how the browser in question will calculate the widths - https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9469

Comment: It is not working because flex is confused between `layout="column" and layout-gt-sm="row"`. Replace `layout="column" to layout="row"` then it is devided into equal widths. Otherwise you have to tell them explicitly `flex=50`.

Comment: OK, but I want these input containers to stack vertically when displayed on a smaller screen

Comment: So use layout for small screen like `layout-xs="column" and layout-sm="colum"` instead of `layout="column"`.

Comment: Yeah I know, it would just be so much cleaner if I could write it as `layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row"` I have this layout used in many places, so its going to me a load of extra attributes will need adding across my files

Comment: if you use `layout="column" layout-gt-sm="row"` then you have to defined flex value as `flex=50`, then its take 50% width of screen of any device its small or large no matter.

Comment: Yeah I found out I could do this earlier, it's just I haven't seen anything in the Angular Material docs to explain this - or is this basic flexbox rules?

Comment: Ok I see this only is a problem for me when I have an input followed by an md-select, see my update